# Eclipse will not run Android project in AVD automatically

Tags: android, eclipse

I recently created a new Android Application project in Eclipse(but this occurs with any Android project). In Run Configurations I've selected "Automatic" and checked my preferred AVD. But when i run the project Eclipse always tries to run it as an AspectJ/Java application - even if the AVD is currently running.

However if i check Manual as the target and select the device myself, everything is fine.

Help?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the configuration and creating a new one?

Comment: Sometimes recreating the actual emulator also helps.  Something to try but not sure if that would be the answer.  I think the main thing I would check is to be sure that the run configuration type you chose was an Android Application config type.  But I guess if you're seeing the AVD selection, it must already be of Android App type.

Answer (score 1):

If you open Run Configuration and Automatic is selected is there any devices listed and ticked? If so. Unselect all devices and just tick Automatic and try it again.

See if it runs...

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant when I said "I've selected "Automatic" and checked my preferred AVD"